# Почему не отрисовывается линия на поверхности (Pygame)?

Tags: python, pygame

Хочу сделать подобие часов в Pygame. Вынес стрелку на отдельную поверхность (sec_surf) для того, чтобы потом её обновлять, чтобы стрелка шла. Но она не отрисовывается в окне. display.update вставил, с координатами вроде все норм.

Код:

```
import pygame
import time

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 360
FPS = 30

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BROWN = (150, 75, 0)


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen.fill(WHITE)


sec_surf = pygame.Surface((200, 200))
sec_surf.fill(WHITE)
screen.blit(sec_surf, (140, 80))


startpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(100, 100)
endpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(195, 100)
angle = 0

pygame.display.set_caption("Clock")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.draw.circle(screen, BROWN, (240, 180), 100, 2)


running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # проверить закрытие окна
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    angle = time.localtime(time.time()).tm_sec * 6
    current_endpoint = startpoint + endpoint.rotate(angle)

    pygame.draw.line(sec_surf, BLACK, startpoint, current_endpoint, 2)

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(30)  



pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что вы рисуете стрелку на поверхности sec_surf, а затем вызываете pygame.display.update() без аргументов, что означает обновление всего экрана, тут надо немного изменит код и все)

```
import pygame
import time

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 360
FPS = 30

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BROWN = (150, 75, 0)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen.fill(WHITE)

# Создаем поверхность для отрисовки стрелки
sec_surf = pygame.Surface((200, 200))
sec_surf.fill(WHITE)
# Рисуем поверхность на экране
screen.blit(sec_surf, (140, 80))

startpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(100, 100)
endpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(95, 0)  # изменил значение, чтобы стрелка была короче
angle = 0

pygame.display.set_caption("Clock")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.draw.circle(screen, BROWN, (240, 180), 100, 2)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # проверить закрытие окна
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    angle = time.localtime(time.time()).tm_sec * 6
    current_endpoint = startpoint + endpoint.rotate(angle)

    sec_surf.fill(WHITE)  # очистка поверхности от предыдущей отрисовки
    pygame.draw.line(sec_surf, BLACK, startpoint, current_endpoint, 2)

    # Копируем поверхность на экран
    screen.blit(sec_surf, (140, 80))
    # Обновляем только прямоугольник с координатами (140, 80, 200, 200)
    pygame.display.update((140, 80, 200, 200))

    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```